# Cannot proceed to checkout in IE11

Tags: magento-1.8, checkout, onepage-checkout

We have a Magento website that a customer cannot proceed to checkout in IE11.  It hits the one step checkout page, and redirects back to the shopping cart.  The contents are still in the cart.  The ssl is valid and working.  Works in IE11 on other computers, along with Firefox, Chrome, and Safari.

Cleared cache, cleared browser cookies, did a complete IE11 restore.  Flushed their DNS. Still same thing, when they hit proceed to checkout on the shopping cart page it redirects back to the cart.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it just this one customer?

Answer (score 1):

I would say this is an isolated issue to the single user. Looking at the analytics for some sites I have worked with they have conversions from IE11. The Magento knowledge base also states it supports:

> Windows:
>
> Internet Explorer 9 and later
>
> Latest stable version of Chrome
>
> Latest stable version of Firefox

Based on this I would recommend looking at this specific visitor machine if they are a repeat visitor.

Answer (score 0):

made a gist her to fix this issue
[enter link description here](https://gist.github.com/roman204/c5468879074826dc9b1eb20a6bc5fca4)